# Mouse pointer misaligned when using Python in IDLE on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, mouse, python-idle

I'm an absolute beginner using Python 3.9.5. When I am editing strings in the interactive shell on IDLE, my mouse pointer is vertically misaligned. When I try to select a certain line of code, it will select the line directly under it instead of selecting the line I want. I was wondering if there is anything I can do to fix this, as it's very frustrating to try and select the lines I want.

Comment: I seconded 'close' because this is not a programming question.  It appears to be glitch involving Apple hardware, macOS, and tcl/tk for macOS.  See https://bugs.python.org/issue24893.  The issue was semi-closed because we do not have a current reproducible example.  It you see this even semi-consistently, please report exact hardware, macOS version, Python installer (python.org or other?), and install options either on issue or here (and I will forward).  My MacbookAir with Mohave and multiple python.org installers has never had this problem.  I only know what is on the issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.